# Good examples/books/resources to learn about applied machine learning (not just ML itself)

Tags: machine-learning, references, train, application

I've taken an ML course previously, but now that I am working with ML related projects at my job, I am struggling quite a bit to actually apply it. I'm sure the stuff I'm doing has been researched/dealt with before, but I can't find specific topics.

All the machine learning examples I find online are very simple (e.g. how to use a KMeans model in Python and look at the predictions). I am looking for good resources on how to actually apply these, and maybe code examples of large scale machine learning implementations and model trainings. I want to learn about how to effectively process and create new data that can make the ML algorithms much more effective.

Answer (score 11):

I do not have knowledge in ML. After a little web searching, I found a reddit thread that lists the following books - all of which are legally downloadable for free. You can research the titles of your interest for details. Also comment if you find any of the books helpful (and why).

**Machine Learning**

- [**Elements of Statistical Learning** Hastie, Tibshirani, Friedman](http://www-stat.stanford.edu/%7Etibs/ElemStatLearn/printings/ESLII_print10.pdf)
- [**Machine Learning and Bayesian Reasoning** David Barber](http://web4.cs.ucl.ac.uk/staff/D.Barber/textbook/090310.pdf)
- [**Gaussian Processes for Machine Learning** Rasmussen and Williams](http://www.gaussianprocess.org/gpml/chapters/RW.pdf)
- [**Information Theory, Inference, and Learning Algorithms** David MacKay](http://www.cs.toronto.edu/%7Emackay/itprnn/book.pdf)
- [**Introduction to Machine Learning** Smola and Vishwanathan](http://alex.smola.org/drafts/thebook.pdf)
- [**A Probabilistic Theory of Pattern Recognition** Devroye, Gyorfi, Lugosi](http://www.szit.bme.hu/%7Egyorfi/pbook.pdf)
- [**Introduction to Information Retrieval** Manning, Rhagavan, Shutze](http://nlp.stanford.edu/IR-book/pdf/irbookprint.pdf)
- [**Forecasting: principles and practice** Hyndman, Athanasopoulos (Online Book)](http://otexts.com/fpp/)

**Probability / Stats**

- [**Introduction to statistical thought** Lavine](https://www.math.umass.edu/%7Elavine/Book/book.pdf)
- [**Basic Probability Theory** Robert Ash](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/%7Er-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf)
- [**Introduction to probability** Grinstead and Snell](http://math.dartmouth.edu/%7Eprob/prob/prob.pdf)
- [**Principle of Uncertainty** Kadane](http://uncertainty.stat.cmu.edu/wp-content/uploads/2011/05/principles-of-uncertainty.pdf)
- [**All of Statistics** Larry Wasserman](http://www.ucl.ac.uk/%7Ermjbale/Stat/wasserman2.pdf)

**Linear Algebra / Optimization**

- [**Linear Algebra, Theory, and Applications** Kuttler](https://math.byu.edu/%7Eklkuttle/Linearalgebra.pdf)
- [**Linear Algebra Done Wrong** Treil](http://www.math.brown.edu/%7Etreil/papers/LADW/LADW.pdf)
- [**Applied Numerical Computing** Vandenberghe](http://www.seas.ucla.edu/%7Evandenbe/103/reader.pdf)
- [**Applied Numerical Linear Algebra** James Demmel](http://uqu.edu.sa/files2/tiny_mce/plugins/filemanager/files/4281667/hamdy/hamdy1/cgfvnv/hamdy2/h1/h2/h3/h4/h5/h6/Applied%20Numerical%20Linear%20.pdf)
- [**Convex Optimization** Boyd and Vandenberghe](http://www.stanford.edu/%7Eboyd/cvxbook/bv_cvxbook.pdf)

**Genetic Algorithm**

- [**A Field Guide to Genetic Programming** Poli, Langdon, McPhee](http://dces.essex.ac.uk/staff/rpoli/gp-field-guide/A_Field_Guide_to_Genetic_Programming.pdf)
- [**Evolved To Win** Sipper](http://www.lulu.com/ie/en/shop/moshe-sipper/evolved-to-win/ebook/product-18719826.html)
- [**Essentials of Metaheuristics** Luke](http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Esean/book/metaheuristics/Essentials.pdf)

Comment: Thank you for the links. I am in the process of checking some of them out, but what I'm more interested in is something which gives practical examples of using the algorithms and training a model. I already have a good basis for how they work mathematically so I don't need to to understand that as much anymore. Given that I have functional models for each of the algorithms (which are widely available), I want to learn how to use these functions to effectively develop a model.

Answer (score 4):

One of the books that I would recommend is [Introduction to Statistical Learning](http://www-bcf.usc.edu/~gareth/ISL/) and it is free to download. This book is easy to follow with exercises in R. Another good one is [Applied Predictive Modeling](http://amzn.com/1461468485)

Answer (score 2):

I think it would be better to follow proceedings of some [machine learning-related conferences](http://www.wikicfp.com/cfp/call?conference=machine%20learning). Such conferences usually have application tracks, where you can find practical applications of machine learning algorithms.

Answer (score 2):

See a list of resources here:
http://mlwhiz.com/blog/2017/03/26/top_data_science_resources_on_the_internet_right_now/

Answer (score 0):

I found [this website](https://www.doradolist.com/) that has book suggestions by world-class professors from MIT, Stanford, UC Berkeley, and more very helpful. In this [section](https://www.doradolist.com/machine-learning.html), there are lists of machine learning books suggested by people like Professor **Yoshua Bengio** and **Yann LeCun** the godfathers of deep learning.